# Registering a redo operation from an async undo with NSUndoManager

Tags: cocoa, nsundomanager

With UndoManager.registerUndo(withTarget:selector:object:) I can register an undo operation, and in the provided selector calling this same method again causes the registration of a redo operation. This works fine unless in the selector I'm calling an async function which then needs to register the redo operation, like this:

```
func job() {  
     doSomething()  
     registerUndo(self, undo)  
}  

func undo() {  
     async {  
          doSomethingElse()  
          registerUndo(self, job)  
     }  
}
```

In this case, both calls to registerUndo() actually register an undo operation, and not an undo and then a redo as I would expect.
Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Is it possible to call `registerUndo` before `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse`?

Comment: I have this same situation. Have you made any progress on this?

Comment: @Willeke For some reason I didn't see your comment. That would be a workaround, but then you have to keep track of whether the operation has completed so that the undo operation simply does nothing in case it hasn't completed.

Comment: @orion Unfortunately not.

Comment: This is really just a weird situation in general. Do you add something to the undo stack because the user did it or because it completes a long time later? Does adding it a long time later make sense? The user may go to undo something newer and totally undo that long running command by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution I found to have a coherent do/undo/redo mechanism is to use an Action object

```swift
class Action {
    var someContextInfo ( like added/removed elements and indexes )
    var actionType ( like add/remove )

    func execute()

    // Returns the symmetric action ( for example `add` will be a `remove` )
    var symmetric: Action 
}

func doAction(action: Action) {  
     action.execute()  
     manager.registerUndo(withTarget: self) { target in
         target.doAction(action.symetric)
     }
}
```

Using this solution makes possible to do/undo/redo asynchronous operations, since you keep the context and keep track of actions ( finished, failed, in progress.. ).

But as said in the comments, it is an uncommon situation.